# Python: How to Use Requests Library to Access Flask RestPlus API hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

I built a rest api using flask restplus and I tested it using the swagger documentation, and it seems to be fully functional and working just fine. I now want to test the API using the python requests library, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid IAP credentials: empty token
```

I imagine this is because I did not authorize using the credentials. I do have access to the service account credentials json file, but just wondering how I pass this into requests?

Code Example:

```
url = 'https://crosssellapi-project-id.appspot.com/auth/login'

r = requests.get(url, headers={'accept': 'application/json'})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish this is using the `google-auth` library for python.

```
$ pip install google-auth
```

I suggest to [create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) a service account, give it the role ***IAP-secured Web App User*** and then download the JSON key for that service account.

Go to ***API's & Services > Credentials*** and copy the `Client ID` of the OAuth 2.0 client you want to use for your API.

Finally use this code snippet to make a request:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

SERVICE_FILENAME = '/path/to/your/service_account_key.json'
API_URL = 'https://YOUR_API_URL'
AUDIENCE = 'YOUR_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'

credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_FILENAME, target_audience=AUDIENCE)

session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

r = session.get(API_URL, headers={'accept': 'application/json'})

print(r.text)
```

If you want to know more about `google-auth` check [this](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thanks so much! I haven't yet tried this out, but where would one get the OAUTH CLIENT ID. I've never actually seen that before

Comment: Go to Security > Identity-Aware Proxy and select the resource where you want to grant access to your GAE app. Then, in the right pane that will appear click on `Add Member`. In _New members_ paste your service account (appengine-iap-test@dao-aa-poc-uyim.iam.gserviceaccount.com). Finally select the role `IAP-secured Web App User` and click on **Save**. Wait some minutes and try again.

Comment: Also, if you go to Security > Identity-Aware Proxy and the following message appears _**Before you can use IAP, you need to configure your OAuth consent screen.**_ configure your consent screen that will provide the OAUTH CLIENT ID.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to overcome the issue, but having trouble using one of the endpoints now. 

Example call:
 r = session.request('POST', api_url, headers={'accept': 'application/json'}, data={'email': <email>,
                                                                                       'password': <password>})

Now I'm getting the error: {"errors": {"": "None is not of type 'object'"}, "message": "Input payload validation failed"}

Comment: I think this a code issue in your server and not for how to create the request. Try to create a new question for it.

Comment: I'm having another issue now where the API is working through the swagger ui but the API is having problems with some get requests that are run through a python script. Logging in and Logging out seem to work though. But the API can't read the authorization header for whatever reason. Like I said though, the swagger ui works flawlessly.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219036/flask-api-token-is-missing